# Copy value from object of base class to object of inherited class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oop, c#-4.0

I have  two objects such as A : B

I want to copy all values from A to B at run time

Code

```
Cow cow = db.Cows.Find(id);

CowDetailViewModel model = new CowDetailViewModel(); //  CowDetailViewModel : Cow
```

I want to copy value from cow variable to model. there are additional properties in CowDetailViewModel  which i would change after copying values.

Comment: you have to copy every property inside 'cow' to 'model'
`model.X = cow.X;
model.Y = cow.Y;`
and so on.

Comment: First rule of asking for help: did you search it yourself first? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198886/c-sharp-using-reflection-to-copy-base-class-properties), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729527/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-base-class-object-to-a-derived-class-reference-with-a) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010123/creating-a-cloned-copy-of-subclass-from-baseclass). If working for it is not your thing (see comment above), use reflection.

Comment: I know about copying each property.. but i was looking for a more need way... i have 10 properties to copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
CowDetailViewModel model = new CowDetailViewModel()
{
     model.Property1 = cow.Property1,
     model.Property2 = cow.Property2
     ////
     ////
};
```

Comment: or define a constructor that takes the base class instance as a parameter and simply write `CowDetailViewModel model = new CowDetailViewModel(cow);`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple extension method to copy all public properties

```
public static class CopyHelper
{
    public static void CopyFrom(this object target, object source)
    {
        foreach (var pS in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (var pT in target.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (pT.Name != pS.Name) continue;
                (pT.GetSetMethod()).Invoke(target, new[] {pS.GetGetMethod().Invoke(source, null)});
            }
        }
    }
}
```