# How to code a reusable function to parse XML and return an ArrayList of objects which can be overridden to return an ArrayList of a subclass

Tags: c#, xml, oop, design-patterns

I am writing a reusable utility class with a function which will take an XML request string as a parameter, and it is supposed to parse the XML response and return an ArrayList of CompanyData objects.

```
public ArrayList ReadCompaniesData(string xmlRequest)
```

The function will send the XML Request to a web service exposed by an Accounting application, which will return some information about multiple companies hosted by that application.

I can create an object called CompanyData with members for the standard properties of a Company. But sometimes, the accounting application can be customized to include additional properties for a company.

In such cases, I will create a subclass of the CompanyData, example: MyCompanyData and I will need to override the method ReadCompaniesData in a subclass of my Utility class. How can this subclass method call the base class method for all the common / standard properties of a Company and then parse the XML response for the specific additional properties?

The problem is that the base class method will return an ArrayList of CompanyData objects, whereas the subclass will need to return an ArrayList of MyCompanyData objects (subclass). I do not want to replicate the entire code in the subclass method; just the additional code to parse the additional properties of the customized Company.

From the base class method, I can return the raw XML response also as an additional out parameter, so that the subclass can parse the additional tags, but how do I change the object type in the ArrayList from CompanyData to MyCompanyData? If it requires creating a new object and copying field by field from CompanyData to MyCompanyData, it will be quite cumbersome.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If you are not stuck below .NET 2, I would totally not use an `ArraList`, but a `List<T>` instead and make the method generic.

Comment: Even if you use a Generic List, you will still need to specify at coding time the type of the generic List, and you will need to instantiate the object CompanyData while populating into that List. This object will not have the additional properties for the specific customized company; so I will still face the same problem.

Comment: You just need to determine what type of object you need to create and then you are all set to use generics.

Comment: The base class method can not determine the type of object to be created. Can I pass a string parameter to specify the type of object, and based on that can I instantiate the generic List and the member object? Can you show a small example?

Comment: You can just put the custom properties in a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah...but I will lose Intellisense features and compile time code checking.

Comment: This answer may work for you.

[Creating a cloned copy of subclass from baseclass][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9010505/1659396

Answer (score 0):

If you need only enumeration of returned collection you can try to change return type of method to `IEnumerable<T>`, which supports generic covariance and can be converted to list or filtered for desired type using extension methods (ToList,Cast,OfType etc),
 move parsing logic to domain classes and instantiate real types in Util classes' templated methods.
 Something like this (I use classes from System.Xml.Linq instead of raw text):

```
 class Company
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual void ParseXml(XElement elem)
    {
        this.Title = elem.Element("Title").Value;
    }
}

class DerivedCompany : Company
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public override void ParseXml(XElement elem)
    {
        base.ParseXml(elem);
        this.Address = elem.Element("Address").Value;
    }
}



  class CompanyUtil
{

    protected virtual Company GenerateRealCompany()
    {
        return new Company();
    }
    public  IEnumerable<Company>  ReadCompanies(XDocument document)
    {
        IList<Company>  companies=new List<Company>();
        foreach (var elem in document.Root.Elements())
        {
            var comp = GenerateRealCompany();
            comp.ParseXml(elem);
            companies.Add(comp);
        }
        return companies;
    }
}

class DerivedCompanyUtil:CompanyUtil
{
    protected override Company GenerateRealCompany()
    {
        return new DerivedCompany();
    }
}
```